# React native:how to reset Login page after login into home page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, autoresetevent

i logined into my home page using api.in react native,on top side it is showing navigate button defaultly,i want to remove or hide that button.then if i logout from that page,in login page have reset text fields. so any one have  about that means,please let me know.

Comment: can you please explain more? can't get what you wanted to do

Comment: i want to remove navigate button,which is defaulty  will come in react native.after login into home page it should not show that navigate button.@JaydeepGalani

Comment: @Aswini are you using `createStackNavigator` ?

Comment: yahh am using createStackNavigator @ShubhamBisht

Comment: Did Jaydeep's answer worked for you?

Comment: yes,it is working to remove navigate button.@ShubhamBisht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your next screen's class where you are navigating add this,

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft : null
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to reset your `TextInput` field on Login screen when user goes back again to Login screen. You can use this.

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

<TextInput 
       placeholder="USERNAME"   
       ref={(u) => this._username = u} // add this to your TextInput
/>
```

And then use this,  `<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={ () => { this._username.clear(); } } />`

For reference checkout this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Comment: but am using createStacknavigator to navigate.and also am not getting how to implement your code in my code. @ShubhamBisht